# Google tv issue

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, google-tv

testing the scripts as per template at:
http://gtv-resources.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/templates/html-02/index.html

i see something is not working properly.

In fact.... if i click two times the same thumbnail ( and we know viewers can do it) **the video player stop working**.
It is like ..... if the server stay on the previous request without take care of the new one.
Because there is not a visual movie preloader i don't know what is happening on server side.

I really hope someone can help me on this issue.
Many thanks
maurizio

Comment: No. we can't help you with this issue. You've provided no code, vague diagnostics.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a bug in the html UI templates. Please file it in the issue tracker with step by step instructions to reproduce this issue:

http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/